# Using select dropdown within the guides to automatically populate cypher query

Tags: neo4j

In the [Create a Custom Browser Guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-create-neo4j-browser-guide/), it talks about using form fields to populate cypher query text in the guide, similar to the built-in `:play query-template`.  This works fine with HTML "input" fields:

```
<article class="guide" ng-controller="AdLibDataController">
   <carousel class="deck container-fluid">
      <slide>
         <input value-for="queryLang" class="form-control" value="Person"/>
         <pre class="code runnable ng-binding" mode="cypher">
            MATCH (n:<span value-key="queryLang">Person</span>) RETURN n
         </pre>
      </slide>
   </carousel>
</article>
```

But, it doesn't appear to work with other form elements.  Is it possible to populate cypher query text in a guide using a select dropdown?  A dropdown list is far more useful than a text field, where someone can mistype the value.  I have tried the following (which doesn't work):

```
<article class="guide" ng-controller="AdLibDataController">
   <carousel class="deck container-fluid">
      <slide>
         <select class="form-select">
            <option value-for="queryLang" value="Movie">Movie</option>
            <option value-for="queryLang" value="Person">Person</option>
         </select>
         <pre class="code runnable ng-binding" mode="cypher">
            MATCH (n:<span value-key="queryLang">Person</span>) RETURN n
         </pre>
      </slide>
   </carousel>
</article>
```

Any suggestions?  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug, or something not (yet) foreseen.

In fact, with the following code:

```
<article class="guide" ng-controller="AdLibDataController">
  <carousel class="deck container-fluid">
    <slide class="row-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div>
          <select value-for="nodeLabelA" class="form-control">
            <option value="Producer">Producer</option>
            <option value="Movie">Movie</option>
            <option value="Actor">Actor</option>
          </select>
          <input value-for="propertyKeyA" class="form-control" value="name" />

          <div class="listingblock">
            <div class="content">
              <pre
                mode="cypher"
                class="highlight pre-scrollable programlisting cm-s-neo code runnable standalone-example ng-binding"
                data-lang="cypher"
                lang="cypher"
              ><!--code class="cypher language-cypher"-->CREATE (a:`<span value-key="nodeLabelA">Another</span>`) RETURN a<!--/code--></pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </slide>

    <slide class="row-fluid"></slide>
  </carousel>
</article>
```

i selected something from the dropdown and the,
with the `<select/>` highlighted, i just type `tab` to go to the next input and the `maiusc+tab` to return to `select` tag.
After that the Cypher code change :|

Indeed, looking at the neo4j browser github code, the `value-for` js part seems to be triggered by `onkeyup`, maybe this is the reason.

Moreover, for some reason, without the second empty `slide` this trick doesn't work.